# Grab an object in Django

Tags: python, django

This is probably very simple and basic but I'm struggling with grabbing a newly-created object in Django. It is for a basic library-style app. Over in models, I do this to create a Book object:

```
def add_book(self, postData, user_id):
    title = postData['title']
    first_name = postData['first_name']
    last_name = postData['last_name']
    user_obj = User.objects.get(id=user_id)

    if not Author.objects.filter(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name).exists():
        author_obj = Author.objects.create(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
    else:
        author_obj = Author.objects.get(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)

    return self.create(title=postData['title'], created_by=user_obj, author=author_obj)
```

Then in views, I call that method and wish to redirect to a page specifically for that newly-created object. I think you can see that I have most of the code down, but don't know what to put in place of the "????".

```
def books_add(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        errors = Book.objects.book_validation(request.POST)

    if not errors:
        Book.objects.add_book(request.POST, request.session['uid'])
        book_id = Book.objects.get(????).id
        return redirect('/books/book/{}/'.format(book_id))
    else:
        context = {
            'errors' : errors,
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1st part use [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) for retrieve or create a model entry

```
def add_book(self, postData, user_id):
    title = postData['title']
    first_name = postData['first_name']
    last_name = postData['last_name']
    user_obj = User.objects.get(id=user_id)

    author_obj, created = Author.objects.get_or_create(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)

    return self.create(title=postData['title'], created_by=user_obj, author=author_obj)
```

2nd part, `return self.create` return a Book entity :

```
def books_add(request): 
    if request.method == "POST": 
        errors = Book.objects.book_validation(request.POST)
    if not errors:
        book = Book.objects.add_book(request.POST, request.session['uid'])
        return redirect('/books/book/{}/'.format(book.id))
    else:
        context = {
            'errors' : errors,
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues here. At the very least, look at Django Forms before you go much further. This is what a view that creates an object could look like:

```
def add_book(request):
    if request.POST:
        author, created = Author.objects.get_or_create(first_name=first_name,
                                                       last_name=last_name)

        book = Book(title = request.POST['title'],  
                    user_obj = request.GET['user'],
                    author = author,)
        book.save()

        return redirect('/books/book/{}/'.format(book.id))

    else:
        return render(request, 'book_form.html')
```

You really need to look into ModelForms to handle your POSTs. But start with looking at [Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/).